# Converter from PSfrag to pinlabel?

Tags: graphics, conversion, psfrag

A lot of legacy TeX files using `PSfrag` exists out there and more is being produced everyday by things like `Xfig`, `Inkscape`, ... I was wondering if anyone has set on a course to write a converter from a document labelled with `PSfrag` to something like `pinlabel`, and if not what are the pitfalls of such path?

It looks like a script would have to:

- Parse the PSfrag code to get the labels and placeholders
- Parse the EPS files to get the coordinates and clean the placeholders
- Convert the coordinates
- Write out the pinlabel coordinates and labels

It looks like the most difficult task is to parse the EPS files... looks messy but doable ...

and finally:

How much of this eps-parsing could exists in `PSfrag` itself?

Comment: if you are prepared to have a dependency on ghostscript then psfrag could dump the coordinates easily enough as that's basically all it does anyway.but would you also want to convert the eps file to a form without the original labels, to overlay th epinlabel ones?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I figured that since I have to parse the EPS to clean it from the placeholders, I could get the coordinates in the same pass.

Comment: Yes sure that's all psfrag is doing, in fact the original version worked as a pre-processor writing out the coordinates to a file used via picture-mode to overlay the typeset labels, I suggested the change to do it all internally in a single postscript pass some time back in the dark ages before lack of compatibility with pdftex was an issue.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do you know how to make ghostscript output the coordinates of a label?

Comment: I did 30 something years ago when working on psfrag, today at 10 to midnight less so:-)